# How can I catch properties of an object's relations in a twig dump?

Tags: debugging, twig, octobercms

I am exploring the possibilities of OctoberCMS in a test project about movies. Each movie has several properties, among others one or more genres (both movies and genres are models btw). I am now trying to code something for the front-end filters on a movie list page, but I am having problems trying to get to the field *genre_title* -see screenshot at https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrIHm.png. When I do `{{ dump(movies.items[0].relations) }}` I see the collection *genres* but from then on I am stuck. I have tried many different things:

- `{{dump(movies.items[0].relations[0].items)}}`
- `{{dump(movies.items[0].relations['genres'].items)}}`
- `{{dump(movies.items[0].relations.items)}}`
- etc.

Most of my attempts gave me NULL as a result. How can I get to the *genre_title*? I'd really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its collection so you can simply need to loop

```
{% for movie in movies %}
    {% for genre in movie.genres %}
        {{ genre.genre_title }} - {{ genre.slug }} - {{dump(genre)}}...
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Now you can have all the data available.

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. My situation was somewhat different in that I am pushing all selected filters to an array so that I can display the active filters somewhere on top of the screen. I noticed that when genres are pushed, it only used the genre-id. Thanks to elements in your answer, I got it working, though. I can only add this comment to this answer, as this is only the second time ever I have been active on this platform. Would have chosen your answer otherwise. Again, thanks!